# Rejecting user stories does not close sub-tasks

Tags: tfs

Let's say I have UserStory1 and sub-tasks Task1, Task2 and Task3.

Business decided that UserStory1 should not be implemented. They changed their minds and they don't want this anymore.

What should I do now?
In my mind, I have to close the UserStory1, change Reason to Rejected and write nice comments explaining why this is rejected. But...

In TFS, when I set UserStory1 to:

Sate: Closed
Reason: Rejected

I was expecting TFS to close Task1, Task2 and Task3 as well but this does not happen. Am I doing something wrong or this is how things are supposed to be? Will I have to close each sub-task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to close them by hand unless you write some server plugin or notification event listener that will do this for you, as the one coming with the scrum4teamsystem template.

Sorry for the bad news...

Comment: The more I use TFS, more I see that there is a lot of space for improvement. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One man's improvement is another man's bug. TFS is also extremely extensible so if you want this, do it yourself and then give it away.